# Disconnecting system load during charging

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-charging, embedded, charging

I'm designing a charging circuit for a single-cell li-ion battery that powers a PCB with high-power LEDs. For safety, I want to disconnect the PCB and the high-power LEDs during charging. Therefore, I need a circuit that has the following properties:

- If the charging voltage is applied to A, the circuit disconnects B and C and connects A and C
- If A is ground, the circuit connects B and C and disconnects A and C

A is the output of the charger, B the positive terminal of the PCB and the high-power LEDs and C is the positive terminal of the battery.

I tried to implement this with a MOSFET, but I think it's not possible using a single one.

Do you have an idea?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ9fpt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A number of PMICs, for example BQ25150 (just to pick one arbitrarily) will do this for you.  In fact, a battery charging IC that separates the load like this is preferred, since it can accurately determine the charging current and cut off charging at an appropriate level.  A system that charges the battery while running off the battery risks overcharging when the current drawn by the load exceeds the end-of-charge current.  Then you're dependent on the backup timer to reduce battery damage due to overcharging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in our case the charging circuit is separated from the actual PCB that is powered by the battery. The charging IC has its own board and is connected to the actual powered PCB only by VBUS, D+, D- and GND. So, we need to modify the powered PCB such that it cuts off the system load when VBUS is present.

Comment: Why cutoff when you can incorporate dual regulation : battery and load at the same time. Insufficient power? (2.4A?) Lack of intelligent control?